# when using libraries from github shall I add an Apache license somewhere in my app?

Tags: android, apache, open-source, licensing

I downloaded few source codes for android 
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Game/List_of_Free_code_Game.htm
from what I see this website doesn't state the license of these source codes anywhere

I want to modify these apps and upload them to play store, or sell them, the problem is that I don't know if I have the right to do this or not. above this, when using libraries with apache license, I don't know the whole app will be considered under this license or just the parts used .

Comment: If there's no explicit license, consider them copyrighted.

Comment: Ah, yes... the programmer's plight of needing a lawyer to navigate license agreements.  This question might be better suited for http://opensource.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This mean I can't use them ?
the title says Free code Game, and in the url it said open source, so it doesn't make sense to put apps there if no one have the right to modify, redistribute them..

Comment: Free-as-in-speech and free-as-in-beer are two *very* different things...

Comment: Yes @KevinKrumwiede! Advertise Open Source! `</blatant-advertising>`

Comment: @Zizouz212 Can't tell if you're being sarcastic or what...

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Nah, I like it when people advertise Open Source. Partly because I'm a mod there :)